# Не правильная дозапись в бинарный файл C#

Tags: c#

Всем доброго времени суток. Помогите разобраться, написал приложение которое производит дозапись бинарного файла, но дозапись только в 101 значение, в чем может быть проблема ?

```
public void Cicle()
{

SectionHelper helper = new SectionHelper();

var Number_s = helper.AllocatedSection(8);

var Year_s = helper.AllocatedSection(8);

var Shift_s = helper.AllocatedSection(3);

var Day_s = helper.AllocatedSection(5);

var Month_s = helper.AllocatedSection(4);

var R_s = helper.AllocatedSection(4); // пока не понял что за параметр.

Int32 Line = 0;

Int32 Line2 = 0;

int Year2 = 0;

int Day2 = 0;

int Month2 = 0;

int Shift2 = 0;

int Rs2 = 0;

int Number2 = 0;

int NumberR = -1;

string path = @"E:\DELETE\n.dat";

string path2 = @"E:\DELETE\nr.dat";
try
{
using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(
                    File.Open(
                    path, 
                    FileMode.Open, 
                    FileAccess.Read, 
                    FileShare.ReadWrite)))
{
using (BinaryReader reader2 = new BinaryReader(
                    File.Open(
                         path2, 
                         FileMode.Open, 
                         FileAccess.Read, 
                         FileShare.ReadWrite)))
{

while (reader.PeekChar() > -1) 
{
Nr++;

Line = reader.ReadInt32();

BitVector32 bv = new BitVector32(Line);

int Number = bv[Number_s];

int Year = bv[Year_s];

int Shift = bv[Shift_s];

int Day = bv[Day_s];

int Month = bv[Month_s];

int Rs = bv[R_s];

if (reader2.PeekChar() > -1)
{
Line2 = reader2.ReadInt32();

BitVector32 bv2 = new BitVector32(Line2);

Number2 = bv2[nr_s];

Year2 = bv2[y_s];

Shift2 = bv2[sm_s];

Day2 = bv2[d_s];

Month2 = bv2[m_s];

Rs2 = bv2[r_s];
}

Console.WriteLine("Начальный параметр Line {0}", Line);
if ((Line != Line2) & (Year > 14))
{
using (BinaryWriter WriteNr = new BinaryWriter(
       File.Open(
       path2,
       FileMode.Append,
       FileAccess.Write,
       FileShare.ReadWrite)
))
{
 WriteNr.Write(Line);

//WriteNr.Close();

 Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
Console.WriteLine("Запись в Nr Line:{0} И Line2:{1}", Line, Line2);
Console.ResetColor();
}

ReadSr _readSr = new ReadSr(
                Line2, 
                Year2, 
                Day2, 
                Month2, 
                Shift2, 
                Nr2);
 if ((_readSr.NumberZ == NumberR) & (_readSr.flag))
{

 }
 else
{
ReadSr _readSr2 = new ReadSr(
       Line, 
       Year, 
       Day, 
       Month, 
       Shift, 
       Nr);
 {
 if (_readSr2.flag)
{
        SaveBinaryNumb save = new SaveBinaryNumb(
               _readSr2.NumberZ, 
               _readSr2.TimeRelease, 
               _readSr2.NumberRoll);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Причем самое интересное файл в размерности растет, и продолжает расти пока не закроешь программу, а так увы не должно быть, потому как идет сравнение данных с одного файла с другим фалом, и если совпадения то пропускать выполнение каких либо действий. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Не совсем в тему, но тяжело читать и разбирать код, в котором вместо человеческих названий переменных сплошняком идут: Rs1, nz, ts, n, ds2, ms, sm и т.д. Вам самому не тошно это видеть?

Comment: @Bulson Если брать в плане эстетики, то такое определение переменных не самое лучше, но так как этот проект восстанавливается по образцу С++, то на этапе отладки удобно, но если вам так принципиально, сейчас отредактирую !

Comment: Это не эстетика, а практичность. Код должен быть читабелен, а не выглядеть как шифровка в Центр.

Comment: @Bulson Еще раз пожалуйста внимательнее, так обозвал переменные не я, а восстанавливать то что уже написано и сравнивать, легче в том виде в котором оно уже есть. Естественно в будущем когда отладка пройдет успешно переменные будут изменены.! Но специально для вас, я поправил свой косяк.

Comment: @Ethernets, как я понимаю, вы в лоб переписываете код на С++ в C#? Зачем? В C# есть средства сериализации/десиреализации, которые освобождают от ручной работы с бинарными потоками.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Потому что я C# только изучаю, и так уж вышло что многих моментов я не знаю, поэтому стараюсь заполнять свои пробелы, и пополнять свою практику и опыт, а в этом мне помогаете вы и данный ресурс. За что Вам и Всем большое Спасибо

Comment: @Ethernets, в данном случае лучше все таки использовать сериализацию. Вы читали Троелсена? Он как раз хорошо освещают эту тему.

Comment: Я попытался скопировать ваш метод в VS. Я правильно понял, что во внутрь открытых using для чтецов вы еще и запихали using для записи? Если да, то это дичь, если честно. И зачем вы сперва создаете кучу переменных, читаете для них значения из файла, а потом создаете объекты и копируете в св-ва этих объектов значения переменных? Нужно было сразу создать экземпляры объектов и сразу в их свойства читать из файла значения. Тяжело, если честно. Вы неправильно действуете, не нужно пытаться таким образом переписывать. Нужно разделить задачу на части и писать заново, заглядывая в старый код.

Comment: @Bulson вы не могли бы приблизительно показать как должно быть ? Я просто не совсем имею представления, и да вы правильно поняли я в using на чтение засунул using  для записи. Спасибо вам за ответ

Comment: @Ethernets, объявите класс, который содержит в себе свойства, которые вы читаете из двоичного файла и пометьте его атрибутом Serialize. После этого вы сможете ~5 строчками кода проделывать то, что вы привели в пример. Почитайте про BinaryFormatter. Да, ручная возня с файлом может быть полезна в отдельных случаях(например, если файл большой), но в данном случаем от этого можно уйти.

Comment: @Ethernets, да, вы можете в лоб переписывать все с с++ на C#, вплоть до ручного управления памятью, но это не правильно. Нужно пытаться транслировать код С++ на примитивы C#, а так же пытаться провести рефакторинг исходного кода, так как возможно, на момент написания кода- это было приемлемо, но прошли многие годы и поменялись технологии и сейчас все это можно переписать в более изяшной манере.

Comment: @iluxa1810 большое спасибо я к этому и стремлюсь, просто мне не хватает так сказать наставничества, но думаю это не проблема с Вашей помощью и помощью остальных специалистов данного ресурса. Спасибо

Comment: @iluxa1810 начал разбираться и понял одну вещь, что я получается прочитать из уже созданного бинарного файла на С++ не смогу с помощью Deserialize ? Тоесть получается, файл который формируется на С++ нужно читать старым методом, а производить запись чтение с помощью Serialize ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разделяй и властвуй древнейший принцип, который годится и для программирования.
Я набросал примерный способ решения вашей задачи с комментариями пожеланиями и пояснениями. Он естественно никак не проверялся на ошибки, считайте это просто Набросок того что должно быть. Раскрашивать и дорисовывать это уже ваша задача.

```
//методы принято называть с английскими глаголами вначале:   Get,Set,Make,Load и т.д.
public void MakeCycle()
{
    //пути к файлам, адреса сайтов и проч. нужно делать
    //приватными константными полями класса
    //или параметрами метода,
    //но не локальными переменными метода
    string pathN = @"E:\DELETE\n.dat";
    string pathNr = @"E:\DELETE\nr.dat";

    //первый список
    List<ReadSr> listReadSr1 = GetListReadSr(pathN, new SectionHelper());
    //проверяем, если получили пустой список, то прерываемся на этом 
    if (!listReadSr1.Any()) return;

    //второй список
    List<ReadSr> listReadSr2 = GetListReadSr(pathNr, new SectionHelper());
    //проверяем, если получили пустой список, то прерываемся на этом 
    if (!listReadSr2.Any()) return;

    //теперь займемся сравнением и записью
    int count = CompareAndWriteReadSrLists(listReadSr1, listReadSr2, pathNr);

}

private List<ReadSr> GetListReadSr(string pathFile, SectionHelper helper)
{
    //локальные переменные именуются со строчной буквы (чтобы отличать их от свойств и классов)
    var lengthNumber = helper.AllocatedSection(8);
    var lengthYear = helper.AllocatedSection(8);
    var lengthShift = helper.AllocatedSection(3);
    var lengthDay = helper.AllocatedSection(5);
    var lengthMonth = helper.AllocatedSection(4);
    var lengthRs = helper.AllocatedSection(4);

    //готовимся
    List<ReadSr> result = new List<ReadSr>();
    ReadSr readSr = null;

    //читаем файл и создаем список объектов типа ReadSr
    try
    {
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(
                    File.Open(
                    pathFile, 
                    FileMode.Open, 
                    FileAccess.Read, 
                    FileShare.ReadWrite)))
        {
            Int32 line = 0;
            BitVector32 bVector = null;

            while (reader.PeekChar() > -1)
            {
                line = reader.ReadInt32();
                bVector = new BitVector32(line);

                //создаем новый экземпляр ReadSr
                //(я не знаю как в этом классе называются свойства, поэтому отсебятина )
                readSr = new ReadSr()
                {
                    Number = bVector[lengthNumber],
                    Year = bVector[lengthYear],
                    Shift = bVector[lengthShift],
                    Day = bVector[lengthDay],
                    Month = bVector[lengthDay],
                    Rs = bVector[lengthRs]
                };
                //добавляем в список новый экземпляр
                result.Add(readSr);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Ошибка чтения файла в методе GetReadSr()");
        return new List<ReadSr>(); //ошибка, тогда пустой список
    }

    return result;
}

private int CompareAndWriteReadSrLists(List<ReadSr> sourceList, List<ReadSr> targetList, string pathFile)
{
    //счетчик записанных элементов, который будем возвращать
    int result = 0;

    try
    {
        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(
            File.Open(
            pathFile,
            FileMode.Append,
            FileAccess.Write,
            FileShare.ReadWrite)))
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < sourceList.Count; i++)
            {
                //если экземпляры не равны и у источника год > 14 
                if (!ReadSrPropertiesCompare(sourceList[i], targetList[i])
                    && (sourceList[i].Year > 14))
                {
                    //пишем в файл
                    writer.Write(sourceList[i]);
                    //счетчик записанных элементов
                    result++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Ошибка записи в файл в методе CompareAndWriteReadSrLists()");
    }

    //
    return result;
}

private bool ReadSrPropertiesCompare(List<ReadSr> sourceElement, List<ReadSr> targetElement)
{
    //здесь сравниваем все свойства у двух экземпляров
    //и если все свойства равны, то возвращаем true

    //а еще лучше в классе сделать override метода Equals()
    //и тогда этот метод бы не понадобился
    //а можно было бы сравнивать sourceElement.Equls(targetElement)
}
```